# Bullet won't fire?

Tags: actionscript-3, movieclip

I have been working on a space invaders game, I currently have no compiling errors finally but my bullets wont fire.

I kind of know where I should be looking to fix the problem but everything I try fails. Am I right in thinking it is to do with the bullet x-y argument?

I have a `Movieclip` symbol in the library named Bullet the same as my `.as` file but the script dose not seem to add the bullets to the scene.

Here is my ship and bullet code.

**ship.as**

```
    package
    {
    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.events.KeyboardEvent;

    /**
     * ...
     * @author Kenny Martin
     */
    public class Ship extends MovieClip 
    {
        private var fireRate:int = 6;
        private var framesSinceFire:int = 0;
        private var bulletHolder:Sprite
        private var leftDown:Boolean = false
        private var rightDown:Boolean = false
        private var firing:Boolean = false
        private var speed:int = 10;
        private var bulletPool:Vector.<Bullet>

        public function Ship(bHolder:Sprite)    
        {
            x = 275;
            y = 350;

            bulletHolder = bHolder;
            addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, addedToStage, false, 0, true);   
        }

        private function fillBulletPool():void 
        {
            bulletPool = Vector.<Bullet>();
            // while counter
            var i:int = 0;

            // while i is less than 25, keep adding bullets
            while (i < 25)
            {
                //if we dont increase i,we risk getting stuck in an infinite loop
                i++;

                //push a new bullet straight into the vector
                bulletPool.push(new Bullet());
            }
        } 

        public function update():void
        {
            // check if left is down and the ship is at least half its width from the edge
            if (leftDown && x > (width / 2))
                x -= speed;

            // check if right is down and the ship is more than half its width from the    right edge
            if (rightDown && x < stage.stageWidth - (width / 2))
                x += speed;

            if (firing && framesSinceFire >= fireRate)
                Fire();
        }
        public function updateBullets():void
        {
            framesSinceFire++;

            updateBullets();

            for (var i:int = 0; i < bulletPool.length; i++)
            {
                bulletPool[i].update();
            }
        }


        public function Fire():void 
        {
            var bullet:Bullet = findBullet();

            if ( bullet != null)
            {
                bullet.activate(x,y);

                bulletHolder.addChild(bullet);

                framesSinceFire = 0;
            }
        }

        private function addedToStage(e:Event):void 
        {
            removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, addedToStage);

            stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, keyDown, false, 0, true);
            stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, keyUp, false, 0, true);
        }

        private function keyUp(e:KeyboardEvent):void 
        {
            // check left arrow
            if (e.keyCode == 37)
                leftDown = false;
            else if (e.keyCode == 39 ) // check right arrow]
                rightDown = false;
            else if ( e.keyCode == 32)// check space bar
                firing = false;
        }

        private function keyDown(e:KeyboardEvent):void 
        {
            // check left arrow
            if (e.keyCode == 37)
                leftDown = true;
            else if (e.keyCode == 39 ) // check right arrow]
                rightDown = true;
            else if ( e.keyCode == 32)// check space bar
                firing = true;
        }

        private function findBullet():Bullet
        {
            // loop through the bulletpool,from 0 to 24(we added 25 bullets to the pool)
            for (var i:int = 0; i < bulletPool.length; i++)
            {
                if (!bulletPool[i].isActive)
                {
                    // if its not active return the bullet for use
                    return bulletPool[i];
                }

            }

            return null;
        }
    }

}
```

**Bullet.as**

```
    package
    {
    import flash.display.MovieClip;

    /**
     * ...
     * @author Kenny Martin
     */
    public class Bullet extends MovieClip 
    {
        public var isActive:Boolean = false
        private var speed:int = 0.2;
        private var _x:int;
        private var _y:int;

        public function Bullet()
        {
            super()
        }

        public function activate(_x:Number,_y:Number)
        {
            isActive = true;
            x = _x;
            y = _y;

        }
        public function deactivate():void
        {
            isActive = false;

            // check we've got a parent before trying to remove ourselves from one
            if (parent)
                parent.removeChild(this);
        }
        public function update():void
        {
            if (isActive)

            // move up the screen
            y -= speed;

            //until we go well past the top of the screen
            if (y < -height)
            {
                deactivate();
            }
        }   
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried to place a `trace` inside `Fire`? Also it's a naming convention to start a function with lowercase letter, capital implies it's constructor, object initialization.

Comment: thanks for the reply appreciate your help. I have traced Fire but i get nothing back in the console output, however being new to coding i am not exactly sure if i traced Fire correctly?

Comment: FYI you're going to have a problem if you ever try to call updateBullets();

Comment: Can you please explain? i don't receive any compiling errors and i am able to move my player/ship across the width of the stage.

Comment: @KennyMartin I mean place inside `Fire()` function this, `trace('fire..')`, if nothing is logged in your console then you function is never being called, that's why you don't see a bullet. Bet yet place another one inside `if` statement.

Comment: Okay i traced fire and as you say nothing is appearing in the console. So how do i go about finding the problem as to why? Thank you again for you time.

Answer (score 1):

You're not calling the `updateBullets` function.
The only call to `updateBullets` is... inside `updateBullets`... which is never called (and would cause a stack overflow if you did call it with a call to itself in there).

You need to move the `updateBullets` function call to `update()`.